# Car ran low on oil, and now won’t start

Tags: chevrolet, oil, smoke, cavalier

I have a 1998 Chevy Cavalier. I ran my car pretty low on oil I think, I hadn’t checked the dip stick in about 2 months, 2 months ago it was full. There would be smoke coming out the hood when I would be done driving. The last time I drove it, the temperature gauge was all the way up. I checked the dip stick and there was almost no oil in there. I added a quart and now it’s just above the “add oil” line. It’s been a few days since I added the oil, now when I try to start it, the car won’t even “click”. How should
I go about this, is the engine damaged? What could I do to try and get this car running again?

Comment: Do all the electricals work. E.g. headlights, wipers etc?

Comment: They all work very slow, wipers move very slowly, and the ac has almost no power. Is it an issue with the battery then? The car has gas

Answer (score 1):

If you added a quart and it was above the add oil line than you were not critically low on oil, so it's very doubtful your engine seized. If you don't even get a click you most likely have a problem with the starter motor, starter switch, or electrical system.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment about the electricals - “ They all work very slow, wipers move very slowly, and the ac has almost no power.”, it sounds very much like you have a flat battery at the moment.

Charge the battery or get a jump start and see how the engine behaves then.